# variable has incomplete type 'void'

Tags: c, pointers, reference, printf

when compiled i am receiving the above error, what might be the possible cause of this error.
I was expecting 65 0 as the output!

```
int main(){
    char c, *cptr;
    void v, *vptr;
    c = 65; v = 0;
    cptr = &c; vptr = &v;
    printf(“ % d % d”, *cptr, *vptr);
}
```

Comment: Declaring `void` variable makes no sense. Also your format string is wrong. Why do you want to use `void`?

Comment: `int v, *vptr;`

Comment: Also note that stdout is usually line-buffered, so it's better to add a newline character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

- `void` means "no data", so declaring a variable with type `void` makes no sense. You should use an integer type.
- You didn't include required header.
- Your format string is wrong (at least non-standard).

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char c, *cptr;
    int v, *vptr;
    c = 65; v = 0;
    cptr = &c; vptr = &v;
    printf("%d %d", *cptr, *vptr);
}
```

Comment: Pedantically: `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed. Thus, all the regular rules for incomplete types apply.